# csv data import into mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql, fgetcsv

Hi I need to import a csv file of 15000 lines.
I m using the fgetcsv function and parsing each and every line..
But I get a timeout error everytime.
The process is too slow and data is oly partially imported.
Is there any way out to make the data import faster and more efficient?

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

 $fname = $_FILES['sel_file']['name'];
 $var = 'Invalid File';
 $chk_ext = explode(".",$fname);

 if(strtolower($chk_ext[1]) == "csv")
 {

     $filename = $_FILES['sel_file']['tmp_name'];
     $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
 $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vpireport");
 $rows = mysql_num_rows($res);
 if($rows>=0)
{
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM vpireport") or die(mysql_error());

    for($i =1;($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE; $i++)
    {
        if($i==1)
        continue;
        $sql = "INSERT into vpireport
                                (item_code,
                                 company_id,
                                 purchase,
                                 purchase_value) 
                                 values
                                (".$data[0].",
                                 ".$data[1].",
                                 ".$data[2].",
                                 ".$data[3].")";
        //echo "$sql";
        mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    }
}

 fclose($handle);
?>
 <script language="javascript">
 alert("Successfully Imported!");
 </script>
 <?
```

}
The problem is everytime it gets stuck in between the import process and displays the following errors:

Error 1 :
Fatal Error: Maximum time limit of 30 seconds exceeded at line 175.

Error 2 :

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'S',0,0)' at line 1

This error I m not able to detect...

The file is imported oly partial everytime.. oly around 200 300 lines out of a 10000 lines..

Comment: If you can share your code and the various complications you are handling maybe people can respond a lot better by suggesting many other avenues.

Comment: @somnath: I have added my code.. I tried set_time_limit(0) but now I m getting some sql syntax error..

Comment: set_time_limit() has nothing to do with the error you are having. Most probably your code was not progressing to that code and expiring due to 30 secs being reached beforehand! This is a different error and needs to be addressed accordingly. Please check my response below my answer for some suggestions I have made.

Answer (score 3):

Set this at the top of the page:

```
set_time_limit ( 0 )
```

It will make the page run endlessly. However, that is not recommended but if you have no other option then cant help!

You can consult the [documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php).

To make it faster, you need to check your the various SQL you are sending and see if you have proper indexes created.

If you are calling user defined functions and these functions are referring to global variables, then you can minimize the time take even more by passing those variables to the function and change the code so that the function refers to those passed variables. Referring to global variables is slower than local variables.

Comment: This is working to some extent but I am getting a sql syntax error which I am not able to recognise.. Can u guess where is  the error ?

Comment: @Neal Looking at the error, we can see data of last 3 columns out of the 4 columns. Seems to me: purchase_value=0, purchase=0 and company_id='S'. Is company_id a char/varchar field? Can you provide the data structure of the table as also remove the comment in echo $sql so that you can see the SQL commands being sent. Provide the last SQL command displayed along with the table structure.

Comment: Additionally, try to use the TRUNCATE TABLE command as @tpaksu mentioned as that is the fastest way to delete records off a table due to the fact that Delete commands are saved in the database log file while truncate table is not. Data deleted by truncate table command can never be restored in the event of a database file disaster.

Answer (score 3):

You can build a batch update string for every 500 lines of csv and then execute it at once if you are doing the mysql inserts on each line. It'll be faster.

Another solution is to read the file with an offset:

1. Read the first 500 lines,
2. Insert them to the database
3. Redirect to csvimporter.php?offset=500
4. Return the 1. step and read the 500 lines starting with offset 500 this time.

Another solution would be setting the timeout limit to 0 with:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Comment: How will that make the whole job faster and efficient?

Comment: If you are talking about the first solution, instead of inserting values to the database line by line, it'll insert 500 rows at once. Can you say that it won't affect the execution?

Comment: Of course it will improve if he needed to dump everything without any peocessing. However, he mentioned he needs to parse each and every line. Means he has logic that processes each line before the dump.

Comment: Ok, but at last it'll execute an INSERT statement right? Unless he neads optimization on the logic part of the line processing, this is the best answer I could think of.

Comment: If he is going to do a line by line insert then your solution will take even more time considering the extra CPU usage to process 1) only 500 lines at once instead of loading the whole resultset and then 2) forwarding to the next page call to load the next 500 lines. Apart from a server with extremely low memory that cant read 15000 lines of data in memory and needs to use hard disk cache all servers will run faster otherwise.

Comment: 1. will be usable if the latency is caused by the mysql server. 2. and 3. will be usable in every condition. The first 2 methods are workarounds, while the 3. one is a proper answer.

Comment: @ tpaksu : I am trying to insert the csv data into a single database table... Each time a csv file is imported, all the previous contents of the database table are erased and data is newly inserted... will breaking the csv file into batches work here? If so den how?

Comment: you can use the method `LOAD DATA INFILE` that @sachinpuri mentioned in his answer. try first executing `TRUNCATE TABLE`, then `LOAD DATA INFILE`. This seems to be the fastest one but I didn't try.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of LOAD DATA INFILE which is a mysql utility, this is much faster than fgetcsv

more information is available on

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Comment: he is doing a line by line parsing! How can he use LOAD DATA with that?

Comment: The format of each line has to be same, i.e no of columns separated by , should be same and and each column should contain same data type. In this case you need not parse each line mysql utility LOAD DATA INFILE will do that for you.

Comment: @Sachin Puri :Can I use this LOAD DATA statement in place of sql INSERT statement in php code as above?

Comment: Yes you can do so. use following query: $q="LOAD DATA INFILE 'F:/www/temp.csv' into table temp FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','";
mysql_query($q);

Comment: does this F:/www/temp.csv refer to the path where my report is stored?

Comment: Yes this is path of .csv file

Comment: I am again n again getting this error now- You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'S',0,0)' at line 1.. I hav checked my csv file its all fine.. I m not able to detect the error.. can u guess it?

Comment: please show me the sql query you are executing and 4-5 lines from your csv file, and also your table structure

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11452/discussion-between-neal-and-sachin-puri)

Answer (score 1):

simply use this @ the beginning of your php import page

```
ini_set('max_execution_time',0);
```

Comment: I ve tried this but I am getting sql syntax error again.. Its reads like this.. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'S',4511.16,4009.92)' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

If this is a one-time exercise, PHPMyAdmin supports Import via CSV.
[import-a-csv-file-to-mysql-via-phpmyadmin](http://vegdave.wordpress.com/2007/05/19/import-a-csv-file-to-mysql-via-phpmyadmin/)

He also notes the user of leveraging MySQL's `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`. This is a very fast way to import data into a database table. [load-data Mysql Docs link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html)

EDIT:

Here is some pseudo-code:

```
// perform the file upload 
$absolute_file_location = upload_file();

// connect to your MySQL database as you would normally
your_mysql_connection();

// execute the query
$query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" . $absolute_file_location . 
         "' INTO TABLE `table_name`
         FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
         LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
         (column1, column2, column3, etc)";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Obviously, you need to ensure good SQL practices to prevent injection, etc.

Comment: he is doing a line by line parsing! How can he use LOAD DATA with that?

Comment: The fundamental problem is loading CSV data into a table. If his CSV file is properly fielded to fit the LOAD DATA method, line-by-line parsing is not necessary.

Comment: @Eric Cope :I m making a front end page for importing the csv file.. I m using php for the importing data from csv to mysql.. How shall I execute this statement in the my php file?

Comment: I edited my answer. its just a MySQL query, so run the query as you would your `INSERT` queries you mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 1):

**PROBLEM:**
There is a huge performance impact on the way you INSERT data into your table. For every one of your records you send an INSERT request to the server, 15000 INSERT requests that's huge!

**SOLUTION:**:
Well you should group your data like the way mysqldump does. In your case you just need three insert statement not 15000 as below:

before the loop write:

`$q = "INSERT into vpireport(item_code,company_id,purchase,purchase_value)values";`

And inside the loop concatenate the records to the query as below:

```
$q .= "($data[0],$data[1],$data[2],$data[3]),";
```

Inside the loop check that the counter is equal to 5000 OR 10000 OR 15000 then insert data to the `vpireprot` table and then set the $q to `INSERT INTO...` again.
run the query and enjoy!!!

Comment: @ علیرضا: I am trying to insert the csv data into a single database table... Each time a csv file is imported, all the previous contents of the database table are erased and data is newly inserted... can send me a sample tutorial for this?

Comment: I don't remember now, it was a while back which I learned it.